# How can I make SWF files be opened with the standalone player?

Tags: nautilus, default-programs

I have installed the standalone Flash debug player to `/usr/lib/flashplayerdebugger` and I can now use it to test within Flash Builder (Eclipse), but I can't make an SWF open with it from Nautilus.  If I right click and select Open With Other Application it is not in the list of programs, and I can't see how to add it.  How can I make it the default application for SWF files opened in Nautilus?

**Update** - *.desktop file

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Flash Player Debuger
Type=Application
Exec=/usr/lib/flashplayerdebugger
Categories=GNOME;Player;AudioVideo;
MimeType=application/x-shockwave-flash;
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I hadn't noticed this myself. In the previous Ubuntu version, you were able to specify as a command an application you wanted to open a specific file-type  with in the `Properties > Open With` window, but now that doesn't seem possible. You might as well file a bug report for this - it is a very important function that got lost.

I can think of a couple of workarounds though.

#### 1. Desktop file approach

This is one "hacker" way of doing it. In order to start, you must first find out the mimetype name of the SWF file:

1. Right-click the file and open `Properties` and stay in the `Basic` tab. Look for the line that says *Type* and write down somewhere the last part of that line that is between parenthesis. It should be named something like `application/swf-flash` or something in that fashion.
2. Now you must create (unless it already exists, in which case you would *edit*) a `*.desktop` file in one of the working `applications` directories mentioned below:

   - `/usr/share/applications/`
   - `/usr/local/share/applications`
   - `~/.local/share/applications` [recommended]

   and in the `MimeType` field include the mimetype you found in the previous step. To do this, simply create new line and write the following:

   ```
   MimeType=application/swf-flash;
   ```

   if you are editing an existing desktop file, append the mimetype you found and a semicolon to the line:

   ```
   MimeType=mimetype1;mimetype2;application/swf-flash;
   ```

   This is a working desktop file that I have come up with while you read:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=Flash Player Debuger
   Type=Application
   Exec=/usr/lib/flashplayerdebugger
   Categories=GNOME;Player;AudioVideo;
   MimeType=application/swf-flash;
   ```

   **Remember to change** `application/swf-flash` **for the working mimetype!**

   Once completed this step, the application you created a `*.desktop` file for should appear in within the other applications in the `Open With` tab in the `Properties` window of any SWF file.

#### 2. Assogiate application

I don't know if this method still works, but I remember an application called `assogiate` which would let you change all the file associations made by the system among other things. You might want to install this, its in the **Software Center**.

Comment: I've followed point 1, replacing the mimetype with `application/x-shockwave-flash`. After a restart SWF files are still opening with Movie Player. Actual `~/.local/share/applications*.desktop`  is in question.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot something in option 1. I put it right before the beginning of option 2. Why is the directory in question? Mind that `*.desktop` refers to any file name with extension `desktop`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the file contents are in the question. I have actually named the file `*.desktop` and I'm unsure what to replace the wildcard with.

Comment: Well, I'm sure `flash-player-debugger.desktop` will do just fine then.

Comment: I renamed the file as you suggested. It hasn't made the option appear in 'Open With' list, but it has automatically added the folling line to the end of the file: `Name[en_GB]=flash-player-debugger`

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the gnash swf players .desktop file, it has a %U at the end of the exec line, added that and it is now visable as a default application.